# Extend reactive crud repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc

Try to extend spring boot `ReactiveCrudRepository` interface to have separate methods for entity insertion and updating. Right now `save()` method differentiate insertion from updating checking ID is provided or not. The idea why I need extend it in this way because coming kafka events with new or modified entities already has filled ID.

CustomReactiveCrudRepository:

```
public interface CustomReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID> extends ReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> Mono<S> insert(S entity);

    <S extends T> Mono<S> update(S entity);

}
```

CustomReactiveCrudRepositoryImpl:

```
public class CustomReactiveCrudRepositoryImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleR2dbcRepository<T, ID> implements CustomReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID> {

    private final RelationalEntityInformation<T, ID> entity;
    private final DatabaseClient                     databaseClient;

    public CustomReactiveCrudRepositoryImpl(RelationalEntityInformation<T, ID> entity, DatabaseClient databaseClient, R2dbcConverter converter, ReactiveDataAccessStrategy accessStrategy) {
        super(entity, databaseClient, converter, accessStrategy);
        this.entity = entity;
        this.databaseClient = databaseClient;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> Mono<S> insert(S objectToSave) {
        Assert.notNull(objectToSave, "Object to save must not be null!");

        return this.databaseClient.insert()
                                  .into(this.entity.getJavaType())
                                  .table(this.entity.getTableName()).using(objectToSave)
                                  // Removed ID generation since it's generated initially
                                  .map((row, rowMetadata) -> objectToSave)
                                  .first()
                                  .defaultIfEmpty(objectToSave);

    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> Mono<S> update(S objectToSave) {
        Assert.notNull(objectToSave, "Object to save must not be null!");

        return this.databaseClient.update()
                                  .table(this.entity.getJavaType())
                                  .table(this.entity.getTableName()).using(objectToSave)
                                  .fetch().rowsUpdated().handle((rowsUpdated, sink) -> {

                if (rowsUpdated == 0) {
                    sink.error(new TransientDataAccessResourceException(
                        String.format("Failed to update table [%s]. Row with Id [%s] does not exist.",
                                      this.entity.getTableName(), this.entity.getId(objectToSave))));
                } else {
                    sink.next(objectToSave);
                }
            });
    }

}
```

FooRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CustomReactiveCrudRepository<Foo, UUID> {}
```

Foo entity:

```
@Data
@Table
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private UUID      id;
    private SomeStatus someStatus;
    private Boolean   someBoolean;

}
```

The above example cause UnsupportedOperationException:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Query derivation not yet supported!
```

How I should extend such functionality in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

It might be not relevant anymore, but here is how I did it (with Spring webflux):

I am using R2dbc, which is creating a `SimpleR2dbcRepository` for every repository.

I created a custom class, which extended the `SimpleR2dbcRepository` called `CustomRepository`. And at a configuration I said `@EnableR2dbcRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomRepository.class)`

Then I could override old methods and create new ones.

Comment: And of course, you still need your custom interface, for your repository, so the method call is available.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are importing `org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.Query`
not `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`